# Copy constructor related compiler error

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, stdthread

I have a resource that is shared between two concurrent threads. The resource contains a vector that both threads need to read and write to. Hence, I make access to the vector exclusive through a mutex. So far so good, sharing of resource works well without any problems.

However, the problem starts when I try to write a copy constructor for sharedResource as follows.

```
class sharedResource{
public:
    sharedResource(){} 
    sharedResource(const sharedResource &other) {
        vec = other.GetVec();
    }
    std::vector<int> GetVec() const {  
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(vecMutex); // Gives error
        return vec;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::mutex vecMutex;
};

int main()
{
    sharedResource bacon1;
    sharedResource bacon2 = bacon1;
    return 0;
}
```

For this code, I get error

```
error C2664: 'std::lock_guard<std::mutex>::lock_guard(const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::mutex' to 'std::mutex &'
```

Could you please explain why am I getting the error and if there is a way to use the mutex without getting the compiler error.

If all else fails, I am going to create a thread unsafe GetVec2 member function, that will return vec without going through lock guard. But I would like to avoid this eventuality.

```
std::vector<int> GetVec2() const {
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: What if you declare the mutex as `mutable`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie didn't know that was an option

Comment: Please review your code for passing *copies* of a mutex versus passing *references*.  When dealing with references, keep in mind any `const`-ness of the methods.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you might want to look into the [Rule of three (or five)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). Chances are, you also want to lock this mutex before your object is moved or destroyed.

Comment: @user3670482 - You are missing an assignment operator.  But something seems strange here -- the mutex is a non-static member variable.  It will be different per instance of `sharedResource`.  So locking the mutex in one instance will have no bearing on the other instance.  In other words, I don't see the utility in your design wrt the mutex.  Someone point out what I'm not seeing here...

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It looks like you're right. He also copies the vector in his copy constructor, so that resource isn't being shared either. OP, you may want to look into using `std::shared_ptr` as part of this class.

Comment: @RedAlert - Usually the synchronization is used to protect a globally shared object.  I don't see anything being globally shared.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the way I have written my code, there is only one instance of sharedResource at the time of concurrent execution. Then, at a later point, I make a copy of my sharedResource instance, all other threads are inactive at this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because `getVec()` is a `const` method but `vecMutex` is not `mutable`.  You should either make `getVec()` non-const so it can modify (acquire) the mutex, or make the mutex `mutable` so it can be acquired by const methods too.  I'd probably do the latter.

Comment: Thanks I got same error in GCC: no matching function for call to ‘std::lock_guard<std::mutex>::lock_guard(const std::mutex&)

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer is to make the `vecMutex` mutable.

```
mutable std::mutex vecMutex;
```

There is another non-standard issue with your code.  Your default and copy constructor are declared incorrectly.  It should be this:

```
sharedResource(){}
sharedResource(const sharedResource &other) 
{
    vec = other.GetVec();
}
```

You're also missing assignment operator.

Comment: Does this explain the error text? I'm trying to see how that's relevant.

Comment: In other words, what is called the `lock_guard` copy constructor?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod - The code as posted by the OP had two errors, the one he noticed, and the other that obviously his compiler let him get away with.  It is the latter I pointed out in the second part of my answer.

Comment: It took me a couple of reads to see what @PaulMcKenzie was saying was the second error. I kept looking at the body of the function, missing the important part.
For the possible benefit of others, he's saying that if you define the functions inline in the class, then you don't need the `sharedResource::`. However, if you put them outside of the class definition, then you'd need to refer to them as `sharedResource::sharedResource()` and `sharedResource::sharedResource(const sharedResource &other)`